# To define an ellipse in terms of a pair of points that lie on its minor axis

Tags: metric-geometry, plane-geometry, conic-sections

Just as an ellipse can be defined in terms of the sum of distances from its foci, that are both points on the major axis, can any ellipse be defined with reference to a pair of suitably chosen points on its **minor** axis? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Consider the ellipse $x^2/a^2+y^2/b^2=1$, with the points $P=(0,\frac{-b}2)$ and $Q=(0,\frac{b}2)$ on the minor axis. Let $X=(x,y)$ be a point on the ellipse.

Then:
\begin{align}
PX^2 &= x^2+(y+b/2)^2\\
PY^2 &=x^2+(y-b/2)^2\\
PX^2-PY^2 &= 2by\\
\frac{PX^2+PY^2 -b^2\!/2}{2a^2} &= \frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{a^2}\\ 
\end{align}

So the equation of the ellipse is $$\frac{PX^2+PY^2-b^2\!/2}{2a^2} + \frac{(PX^2-PY^2)^2}{4b^2}\left(\frac{1}{b^2}-\frac{1}{a^2}\right) = 1$$

Comment: I agree with all that, but the question "do any points on the minor axis have properties comparably intuitive to the foci?" is different from what was asked. The answer here should help clarify that the question about intuitive points has an answer of no.

Comment: Will you revert this question to the version when I answered it? It is rude to change a question in a way that invalidates an answer, and in this case it would be easy to ask the new question separately.

Comment: I ask you again to revert this question to the version when I answered it.

Comment: reverted. since the minor axis is also an axis of symmetry, i would still suspect that there may be defining points on it - perhaps we could call them co-foci, if they exist - which also have intuitive properties.